# Como adicionar elementos na posição "x" de um std::vetor

Tags: c++, vector

Como proceder para adicionar um elemento na posição que eu indicar em um `std::vector`? Não é para deletar o que já possui, mas é para adicionar no meio. Segue exemplo:

Vamos supor que dentro de um `std::vector` possua os elementos

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

E eu queira adicionar um numero antes do 4 e depois do 3, mas sem deletar nenhum elemento, ficando assim:

```
{1,2,3,10,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Como proceder? Isto é possível de ser feito? Ou preciso utilizar algum outro *container*, como o `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), mas precisa criar um iterador:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main () {
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    auto it = vec.begin();
    vec.insert(it + 3, 10);
    for (auto x: vec) std::cout << ' ' << x;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7bg4Er). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nzvixfrp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/InsertElements.cpp).

Se fizer corretamente, medir e a performance não agradar, então precisa usar outra estrutura que tenha outros compromissos. Um `list` pode ser uma opção. Ela pode fazer inserção no meio com complexidade O(1). Mas outras operações não são tão rápidas quanto o `vector`.Não conserte uma coisa e quebre outra. Veja o que é prioridade. Quem sabe outra estrutura seja mais adequada. Não existe estrutura perfeita onde tudo ótimo.

Comment: Bom, existe alguma outra forma mais rápida de fazer isto? Aqui no meu programa deu um lag... Obg

Comment: Duvido que exista, mas não é para ser muito lento não. Não sei como está usando, então não posso falar se está certo. Mas se realmente houver um problema de performance, aí tem que usar uma outra estrutura de dados que permita inserção de forma mais rápida, abrindo mão de alguma característica que o `vector` tem, por exemplo, `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Existe o método insert exatamente para isso. Ele insere o elemento em determinada posicao e arrasta o resto do vetor para frente.
Pode fazer assim:
SeuVetor.insert(SeuVetor.begin()+posicao, SeuVetor[posicao]).